# selenium webdriver select dropdown value

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

1.1. go to http://testingapp.workspez.com/login, and click sign up. the 2nd row, left side item, business industry drown box , i am trying to test it.

2.the code below tries to get the business industry drop down by doing `driver.findElement(By.id("field_businessIndustry")` but it fails. get the error

`org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been 'select' but was 'div'`

So how does one get the drop down value? I have tried all codes.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void BrowserOpen() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\rahul\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32_83\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://testingapp.workspez.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Sign up']"));
    login.click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
}

@Test
public void input_field_data() {
    Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("field_businessIndustry")));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because that is not a regular select(a select element).
In order to work it should be a `<select>`

In this case you have a multi-select, you need to click on the `div` wait until your option is displayed and then click it.

> You can ctrl/command + click on the `Select` and see the documentation

Comment: i managed to click on the div, and how do you click on the drop down value later?

Comment: Use xpath like: `//li[text()='Consultancy']`

Comment: Thanks. this like works, but not stable. sometimes i can't click on the dropdown and scroll down

Comment: this comes into work the framework setup, you should have a base page to handle all the waiting and exceptions, and use it like `page.selectFrom(option, selector)` and `page.selectMultipleFrom(option, selector)` and `page.click(selector)` look for dave haeffner videos on youtube to have an idea